# VBA Delete All Objects in Row 1

Tags: excel, vba

The below code copies row 1 from sheet "Template" and pastes it to row 1 of all other sheets in the workbook.

This copy/paste macro is run manually after a change to row 1 on sheet "Template", so that row 1 on all other sheets is identical to it.

Row 1 contains values and objects (shapes & buttons) which also need to be copied/pasted. The issue I've had is that the shapes and buttons have been doubling (stacked on top of each other) on each sheet, each time the macro is run, rather than be replaced as the values are. Through experimentation it seems that this is unavoidable.

Instead I am trying to delete the objects in row 1 of all other sheets (Template excluded), prior to the paste, in order to maintain single copies of objects. My extremely poor vba however is undoubtedly resulting in a run-time error on `shp.Delete`

```
Sub UpdateHeaderRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim HeaderRow As Range
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim r As Range
    
    Set HeaderRow = Worksheets("Template").Range("1:1")
    Set r = Range("1:1")

    HeaderRow.Copy
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Template" Then
        
            For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
                Shp.Delete
            Next Shp
            
            ws.Range(HeaderRow.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ws.Paste
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: The code should work as it is. Is there any sheet protection on a specific sheet? Does the code return this error on all sheets?

Comment: Yes they were protected. I just tried without protection and it worked, however I have ```UserInterFaceOnly:=True``` set in the protection macro which has been effective for all other macros that run while protected.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You should unprotect and protect after deletion **in code**.

Comment: Ok. I am surprised that is the only issue as I have literally no idea with vba. Is ```For Each Shp In ws.Shapes``` ```Shp.Delete``` ```Next Shp``` the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I already told you. UnProtect before the loop and Protect after...

Comment: yes understood, i meant aside from that, but ok, thanks

Comment: Now, can you show us how did you protect the sheet, using `UserInterFaceOnly:=True`? What else from the protection method did you also use?

Comment: ```ws.Protect "password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True``` I was of the understanding this would allow all vba.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Please unprotect all sheets and then use your code. It should be possible to protect, at least, one of them in a different way, I think.

Comment: Please, try `ws.Protect password:="", UserinterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False`. Otherwise, it looks you cannot even select them... Can you?

Comment: same runtime error

Comment: What Excel version do you use?

Comment: 2007.....................

Comment: I know that some versions are insensitive to `UserinterfaceOnly:=True` in terms of shapes. Probably, your version is a problematic one, from this point of view. You should unprotect - protect before the loop and after, which will be any version compatible... I asked you: Can you select a shape after your way of sheet protection?

Comment: yes it has had its issues, will do the protect/unprotect, thanks

Comment: not sure what happened earlier but UserinterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False is actually working in 2007, however obviously leaves the shapes unprotected for accidental deletion by the user.